# in xampp apache not starting showing error

Tags: php, apache, visual-c++, xampp

when I want to start apche it shows me some error like

```
the program can't start because api-ms-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing.
```

for that solution I tried to install vc++ redisrtibuted library but it shows agian error `0x8024007` . I am stuck now.your any help will be appriciated.

Comment: I assume this is on a windows server?  Can you provide more information such as the operating system you're using, the version of Apache you're trying to install, and the method you used to install apache.  If you're looking for something quick and easy, [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) might be a better solution.  It's the full Apache, MySQL, PHP package in a nice little installer for windows/mac/linux.

Comment: I m using windows 7..latest xampp I am using (.7)